# Is it possible to split USB 2.0 control requests?

Tags: microcontroller, usb

I'm developing an application for microcontroller with onboard USB. The application is supposed to be as portable as possible, so I can't just point to one family in particular.

I'm in the process of reading a device's configuration descriptor, however, it is too long to fit in my internal buffer.
I can't use dynamic memory for this, so a buffer for control transfers needs to be statically allocated and I really want to minimize its size given that it won't be used much. So assigning it a couple Kb just for this cfg descriptor is not an option.

I haven't found it in the standard, but maybe I just haven't looked good enough... is it possible to split control **requests** into multiple ones? For instance, request 128 (or whatever) bytes of the cfg desc, then request another 128 bytes of the same descriptor, of course, these would have to be returned with a 128 offset to account for the ones already read, and so on.

Is this possible?

Thank you all for you time.

Comment: I believe you can limit the size transferred, but you can't start at some offset.  The obvious way to solve that (may or may not be the best) is to keep track yourself of where you are and request the same thing multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to SE, by the way.

Comment: Thanks =)  The problem is that I can't fit the entire descriptor in memory, so I can't just request it multiple times because I'll never have it whole. For instance, lets say I have a 1k buffer and the descriptor is 2.5k.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that this is USB, not UART, SPI, or other byte-at-a-time protocol.  But, if somehow you *can* watch individual bytes come in, then my idea still holds.  To read something in the middle, just let the first N bytes go by before you start recording.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I was hoping something like this was possible so I wouldn't have to modify the lower-level drivers (which would help portability a lot)... but I guess not =(

Comment: Not too long ago, I wrote a USB HID driver for the device end, and I remember something in the spec about limited-size transfers.  I don't remember all the details though, so it could have referred to the limited size of a HID packet in general.  Let's wait and see if someone else chimes in.

Comment: You made me realize I mixed the terms transaction and request in my question, I'll fix that up. I think the transfer limit is implementation dependent on the host side. Thank you for help, I'll wait and see if someone can comment further on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of requesting the configuration descriptor and getting all of the interface and endpoint descriptors together, you could request the descriptors one at a time. A device descriptor is 18 bytes, and the other standard descriptors are even smaller. (Class descriptors might be larger, so pick the largest one you need as the buffer size.) You'll need to parse the descriptors to figure out what else to request, but that's not much extra work. The device descriptor gives the number of configurations, config gives the number of interfaces, and interface gives the number of endpoints and the class.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realize I could do that. You mean requesting the cfg desc just enough to parse how many interfaces there are and then request each interface (and endpoints) descriptor one at a time?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.